# Dynamically import modules inside the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, exec

I have a function inside the class which imports the modules dynamically. The modules are to be imported from outside of the working directory.

```
    def dynamic_import(self,name):
        sys.path.append(os.getenv("TEMPLATE"))
        exec('from templates.{} import template_attribute'.format(name))
        print(template_attribute)
```

I have set env TEMPLATE to path to template.
when I pass **name = 'template1'** when it should import template_attribute from **template1**.

This is not working inside the function.
When I run same lines (except function) in python terminal its working.

I tried by replacing `exec` with `__import__`

Like this

```
template_attribute = getattr(__import__(f'templates.{name}'), 'template_attribute')
```

This is also not working.

How do I make it work correctly ?

One more question if `template_attribute` is imported like this, can this be used inside the other functions inside the class ? (or other functions called from this )

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically import a module like this:

```py
import importlib

def dynamic_import(name):
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
    return module

module = dynamic_import('mymodule')
# use module like this
ta = module.mymodule
```